# Что изображено на картинке?

Tags: api, искусственный-интеллект

Наткнулся на [этот сервис](https://everypixel.com/aesthetics), возник вопрос, существует ли такие же API сервисы, в который я могу отослать изображение и получить ответ, что содержится на картинке? Таким образом хочу убрать ручную модерацию загруженных на сайт (PHP YII2) изображений, которая направлена на противодействие загрузки, к примеру, порнографических картинок.

Comment: Убрать ручную модерацию — не получится. Ни одно существующее на данный момент автоматическое распознавание картинок не позволит распознать абсолютно все порнографические картинки

Comment: в любом случае, существуют ли такие сервисы?

Comment: вы можете отправить POST запрос на https://api.everypixel.com/v1/keywords и получить ответ. Смотрите на Network на сайте, которую вы сказали.

Comment: @andreymal я мог бы попробовать распознать. Мой Email в профиле...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я бы начал с создания системы жалоб. Достаточно усложнить процесс создания аккаунта(каптча + почта + телефон, по бюджету) и дать возможность жаловаться на картинки. А в результате проверки изображения алгоритмом уже либо будет даваться первый репорт, либо нет. Очевидно, конечно, но пока что в большинстве проектов все так и происходит(даже без начальной проверки).
  Нейронные сети - дело затратное в плане потребления ресурсов, так что такой функционал будет либо платным, либо будет предоставляться в ограниченом объеме. Как вариант - [SightEngine](https://sightengine.com). 
  Также можно уйти от идеи об использовании API и реализовать требуемый функционал на сервере - [NudePy](https://github.com/hhatto/nude.py), [node-nude](https://github.com/chadsmith/node-nude), [php-nudity-detector](https://github.com/FreebieStock/php-nudity-detector). Или же на клиенте - [NudeJS](https://www.patrick-wied.at/static/nudejs/), но тут нет гарантии что злоумышленник, который нацеленно атакует ваш сервис, не будет отправлять картинку напрямую. Можно объединить два подхода, давая при загрузке картинки оценку для системы репортов, которая зависит от результатов прохождения двух и более тестов. 
  Универсальных решений нет, все зависит от проекта...

Answer (score 3):

Альтернативное предложение - использование сервиса [Mechanical Turk от Amazon](https://www.mturk.com/). Роль интеллектуальных агентов там выполняют человеческие существа - "туркеры", причем очень недорого :)

Смысл в том, что на каждую загруженную картинку автоматически через Amazon API boto3 создавать задачу, задача попадает в очередь, кто-то кто там тусуется берет ее и выполняет. Типичная стоимость такой задачи - 1-2 цента. Там достаточно людей, готовых за 1 цент кликнуть на ссылку и ответить на вопрос "является ли картинка приличной? [да | нет]". Ответ вы можете забрать тоже автоматически через boto3, также можно автоматом подтвердить задачу и зачислить туркеру средства. 
Для надежности можно требовать выполнить одну задачу (проверку одной картинки) 2-3 туркерами, по выполнении скриптом сравнить ответы, если ответы не сходятся - давать сигнал и проверять кому-то вручную, а на тех кто дал неверные ответы жаловаться - их заблокируют.

Вот такой вот технологический регресс в области искусственного интеллекта - людей машины так просто не победят. Любая система AI для проверки картинок выйдет дороже и работать будет хуже. Пока так. Есть множество похожих сервисов, ценность их, разумеется, прямо пропорциональна количеству/качеству "туркеров" на ней тусующихся - MTURK в этой области лидер.

P.S. Предложение модераторам - создать метку mechanical-turk, эта технология уже довольно популярная.

Comment: Метка mechanical-turk готова